# Split string and replace

Tags: sql-server-2005, string

I have a `varchar` column with Url's with data that looks like this:

```
http://google.mews.......http://www.somesite.com
```

I want to get rid of the first http and keep the second one so the row above would result in:

```
http://www.somesite.com
```

I've tried using `split()` but can't get it to work

Thanks

Comment: What programming language are you working with?

Comment: You seem to be talking about string manipulation in a database? If that's the case, please tag your question with the database you are using, as without knowing this, no useful answer can be given.

Comment: What database are you using? You can use a combination of the  lastIndexof() and substring() function if your database supports it?

Comment: I've updated the tags - using Sql server 2005

Comment: Are all of the URLs definitely `http:` or might you have some `https:` in there?

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to do this using T-SQL, you can try something in the lines of:

```
-- assume @v is the variable holding the URL
SELECT SUBSTRING(@v, PATINDEX('%_http://%', @v) + 1, LEN(@v))
```

This will return the start position of the first http:// that has before it at least one character (hence the '%_' before it and the + 1 offset).

Answer (score 2):

If the first URL always starts right from the beginning of the string, you can use `SUBSTRING()` & `CHARINDEX()`:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(column, CHARINDEX('http://', column, 2), LEN(column))
FROM table
```

`CHARINDEX` simply searches a string for a substring and returns the substring's starting position within the string. Its third argument is optional and, if set, specifies the search starting position, in this case it's `2` so it didn't hit the first `http://`.